# can't link to js and css in local directory

Tags: javascript, css

I have a laptop that rarely has internet connection. But I need Bootstrap and jQuery, so I decided to create local jQuery file and download Bootstrap and link to them in html file. So I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="D:/Bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` but it doesn't work. Same with jQuery. So I guess I don't specify paths to the files correctly. Or where's my mistake?

P.S. Codecademy forum says I do everything correctly

```
windows:
href="C:\users\documents\username\web\stylesheet.css"
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try using `href="file:///D:/..."`?

Comment: @RetroCraft same result. But when I use <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> it works. Why? Both has same code

Answer (score 0):

Don't link to a full path, but to the path from your `index.html`

So, if you had your structure like this:

> - index.html
> - [css]  - folder
>
>   - [css]/bootstrap.min.css
>   - [css]/someotherfile.js

In your `index.html` you should link as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/botstrap.min.css">
```

*Technically you can still link with fullpath, but it's unnecessary and often creates confusion / you miss a slash and whatnot.*

Comment: no, html is in **D:/projects/project1/main.html** and css in **D:/Bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css**

Comment: I don't know your exact path. What I'm saying is, your bootstrap should be in the same folder as your project anyways.

Comment: didn't know that bootstrap should be in the same folder. Guess that's what causes the problem

Comment: it doesn't necessarily have to be, but it is the common norm amongst programmers and makes linking much easier

Answer (score 0):

This is Hard to say What mistake you are doing Mostly Chances are as follows:-

1. Using full path instead of a relative path
2. Using Improper filenames

Or you can check these using chrome network panel weather these files are actually loading or creating 404

**OR**

I founded a starter kit which contains HTML, CSS, javascript, bootstrap and jquery
download it from GitHub from [Here](https://github.com/adsingh14/Bootstrap-4-Starter-Kit)

Answer (score 0):

@j_noe . Then if that is the case, to link to your **CSS** file try this in your **html** file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../../Bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
This is on assumption that :- your html is in *D:/projects/project1/main.html* and css in *D:/Bootstrap-4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css*